# Continuously changing Dimensions of a Rectangle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The dimension of a rectangle are continousl changing. The width increases at  a rate of 3 in/s while the length decreases at the rate of 2 in/s. At one instant the rectangle is a 20-in square. How fast is its area changing 3 seconds later?

The answer is -16.
$$\begin{align}A &= LW,\, 20 = LW \\[1ex]
    \frac{dA}{dt} &= L\frac{dW}{dt} + W\frac{dL}{dt}\\[1ex]
    \frac{dA}{dt} &= \frac{20}W\cdot 3 + W\cdot(-2)\\[2ex]
    t=3\implies W &= (3\text{ in/s})*3\text s = 9\text { in}\\[1ex]
    \frac{dA}{dt} &= \frac{20}9\cdot3 + 9\cdot(-2) = \frac{34}3\end{align}$$

Is my assumption at t=3 wrong? any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for dA/dt is correct.  All you need to do is substitute the correct values.  In this case, we know that L=W=20 at t=0.  At t=3 them, L=20-3*2 and W=20+3*3. dW/dt and dL/dt were given.  If you substitute these values in your equation for dA/dt, you will get the expected answer. Note that your value for W at t=3 is not correct; you forgot to take into account the value at t=0.

Comment: I was misinterpreting 20-in square as area! I never thought of it as 20=L, 20=W

Comment: "At one instant the rectangle is a 20-in square. " this wording does not lead to $L=W=20$ - Maybe its an English thing...

Answer (score 1):

"The rectangle is a 20-in square" means that it is a $20\times 20$ square; that is, $L(0) = W(0) = 20$. Three seconds later, $L(3) = 20-3\cdot 2 = 14$ and $W(3) = 20 + 3\cdot 3 = 29$, so that
$$
\frac{dA}{dt}\bigg\lvert_{t=3} 
    = L(3)\frac{dW}{dt}\bigg\lvert_{t=3} + W(3)\frac{dL}{dt}\bigg\lvert_{t=3}
    = 14\cdot 3 + 29(-2) = -16.$$

Comment: units ... -16 in/s